# (REACT) Setting a default value to a Dropdown field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I am making a simple frontend to showcase CRUD RESTful API behavior. One of the requirements is, when the option "GET" is selected, to set as a default at the Dropdown field shown in the picture "Order-by" the value "Name". However, for all the other options, the value should be default "None".

[This is how the specific part of the frontend looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kttO.png)

`const [selectedOrder, setSelectedOrder] = React.useState('');`

`const handleOrderChange = (event) => { setSelectedOrder(event.target.value); }`

So far, the attribute "selected" doesn't work because the state of the field changes. Setting the defaultValue to name also doesn't work.

`

```
Order-by: &nbsp;

<select name="order-by" value={selectedOrder} onChange={handleOrderChange}>

    <option value="">None</option>

    <option value="name" disabled={!isOptionDisabled("GET")}>Name</option>

    <option value="iso" disabled={!isOptionDisabled("GET")}>ISO</option>

    <option value="year" disabled={!isOptionDisabled("GET", "GET emission")}>Year</option>

    <option value="population" disabled={!isOptionDisabled("GET energy per capita")}>Population</option>

</select>
```

`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've reviewed your question about setting a default value for a dropdown field in React, especially when a specific option ("GET") is selected. To achieve this, you can use React's `useState` and `useEffect` hooks to dynamically set the default value based on another state or condition.

Here's an example approach based on your description:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(''); // State for the option that triggers the change
  const [selectedOrder, setSelectedOrder] = useState('');  // State for the order dropdown

  // Function to handle change in the option dropdown
  const handleOptionChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedOption(event.target.value);
  };

  // Function to handle change in the order dropdown
  const handleOrderChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedOrder(event.target.value);
  };

  // Use useEffect to update the order dropdown based on the selected option
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedOption === 'GET') {
      setSelectedOrder('name');
    } else {
      setSelectedOrder('None');
    }
  }, [selectedOption]); // Dependency array ensures this runs when selectedOption changes

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Option Dropdown */}
      <select value={selectedOption} onChange={handleOptionChange}>
        {/* Options here */}
      </select>

      {/* Order-by Dropdown */}
      <select value={selectedOrder} onChange={handleOrderChange}>
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="name">Name</option>
        {/* Other options */}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In this code:

- When the `selectedOption` changes, the `useEffect` hook updates the `selectedOrder` state.
- If the `selectedOption` is "GET", it sets `selectedOrder` to "name". Otherwise, it sets it to "None".
- This approach ensures that the dropdown's value is controlled by React state and updates appropriately based on user interaction or other conditions.

This should solve the issue of setting a default value in the dropdown based on another selection.

Comment: This is another ChatGPT answer.